# Logging from an impersonated thread in a system process

Tags: winapi

There is an ever running process running in system session, let's call it process `A`.

I call a thread `t1` from `A`. `t1` is impersonated to the current logged on user session. The current user is a standard user.

The process `A` creates another process `B` with the same standard user's token.

The logs for process `A`, thread `t1` and process `B` are all written inside program files folder.

The standard user doesn't have access to edit the logs.

Process `A` is able to log inside program files folder since it runs in system session.

Process `B` is unable to log inside program files folder (expected). But thread `t1` is able to log inside program files folder.

How is the impersonated thread able to log inside program files even though process `B` with same impersonation token wasn't able to?

Comment: "*The logs ... are all written inside **program files** folder*" - Why? They don't belong there. Only installed programs and their support/dependancy files should be in there. Application files created at runtime should be in an application-defined folder underneath `%APPDATA%` instead, for instance.

Comment: "*How is the impersonated thread able to log inside program files even though process `B` with same impersonation token wasn't able to?*" - When `B` fails to log, what is the actual error code that is reported? Is is an access denied error, or a sharing violation error, or something else?

Comment: Impossible say how, when unknown how t1 do log

Comment: Unrelated to the immediate issue, but really, people need to stop inventing their own logging infrastructure. [Event Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/event-tracing-portal) is a system service that any application can (and should) be using instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau impersonation was newly added to the existing code that used to run in system session. I was expecting the logging from the impersonated thread to break but it didn't, couldn't figure in the documentation as well. hence raised this.